# Laravel 9: Component constructor default parameters

Tags: php, laravel-9, php-8.1

In the component constructor, I always set the default value for attributes (Laravel v7-8, PHP 7.4).

**Version**
PHP 8.1.4
Laravel 9.6.0

```
public $type;
public $message;

public function __construct($type = 'error', $message)
{
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->message = $message;
}
```

In Laravel 9 (new installation) when i try:

I get this error:

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $type ]]
> in class App\View\Components\Alert

When I try:
`<x-alert type="success" message="my message"/>`, its all ok. So it seems the class ignores the default parameter in the constructor.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `__construct($message, $type = 'error')`

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to medilies:

"As of PHP 8.0.0, declaring mandatory arguments after optional arguments is deprecated."